# Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at upgrading linux-header

Tags: apt, upgrade, 18.04, linux-headers

Whenever I try to get my system up-to-date in Ubuntu 18.04, it stops:
[image: stuck] 
whenever it reaches `Setting up linux-headers-<version>-generic`. I cannot cancel the upgrading from there, but even when you and leave it for hours, it doesn't change anything. If I check the process in `htop` it shows it now doing anything. If I force the upgrade to end and try to restart it, when I retry the upgrade it says a previous one has been interrupted and I should try it with `sudo dpkg --configure -a` which fixes the problem.

I just find it very annoying to have to do this every time there is a header-upgrade available, especially because I feel like it shouldn't happen and there should be a more permanent fix available. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you run that command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`?

Comment: Yes, that did solve it. But I only get that option after I break the upgrade in the first place and it feels wrong to use a solution like this instead of a more permanent solution.

Comment: There is no permanent solution but Ubuntu has mechanisms in place to handle these when they occur, but of course routine updates also help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**TLDR: Disable Secure Boot.**

I started having this same issue about a month ago. For me it turns out the solution was disabling Secure Boot. I've had Secure Boot disabled since I installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it's upgraded without any problems. However, about a month ago, I updated my BIOS which re-enabled Secure Boot (I didn't know this at the time). It was frustrating having the upgrades freeze and I finally figured it out because my VirtualBox installation was also not working. The fix for VirtualBox was disabling Secure Boot which also fixed my `linux-headers-<version>-generic` upgrades.

As noted in the question, it would freeze here:

```
...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ...
```

After disabling Secure Boot, I get:

```
...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-38-generic (4.15.0-38.41) ...
/etc/kernel/header_postinst.d/dkms:
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
...
done
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I got hung up at the same place... rebooted, disabled secure boot, successfully updated, rebooted and re-enabled secure boot, and went on my merry way.

Answer (score 7):

My solution;

- ps aux | grep apt
- Kill the apt process
- sudo dpkg --configure -a
- apt update
- apt upgrade

Answer (score 1):

You may check the answer on `/var/log/apt/term.log`. This is the location for the `apt-get` log. You can also check the `dpkg` log file `/var/log/dpkg.log` `apt` or `apt-get` you are using are based on `dpkg` internal.

One more thing you can identify the process by ID and run `strace -p` to check exactly why it stops.

This is rather a general answer to this or similar questions.

Comment: Adding this to my personal diagnostic notes. Excellent tip. Thanks.