# apt upgrade hanging on "linux-headers-4.4.0-146-generic (4.4.0-146.172)"

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade

apt upgrade has been stuck at the following for a day or two now:

[image: apt upgrade stuck at linux-headers-4.4.0-146-generic (4.4.0-146.172)]

---

**Q1:** What is the best practice for solving this issue?

I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, as recommended here for "gracefully" terminating the process, but it hasn't worked: 
[How to safely abort apt-get install?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253925/how-to-safely-abort-apt-get-install/253933#comment317757_253933) 
Do I follow the second answer instead?

---

**Q2:** How can I avoid this in future?

It looks like it's been reported as a bug here:

https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5580909.html

So how likely is this to happen again?

---

**Edit:**
Seems like it could be linked to this 
[Ubuntu 18.04 stuck at upgrading linux-header](https://askubuntu.com/q/1068828/641390) 
although AFAIK I've had Secure Boot disabled for ages 
Could an update have re-enabled Secure Boot somehow?

Answer (score 1):

In the end I followed [this method](https://askubuntu.com/a/253946/641390).

Running `apt upgrade` then prompted me for a new Secure Boot password, but otherwise completed successfully.