# ubuntu 18.04.02 - sudo apt upgrade - stuck

Tags: apt, 18.04, upgrade

I am a newbie to ubuntu. I was trying to install `tlp`, so I entered the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

and the terminal is now stuck at 70% for a long time. [A screenshot of the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SljhQ.png).

What should I do in this case? Is it safe to force stop it?
Thanks

Terminal full output:

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.15.0-50 linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic
  linux-headers-4.18.0-20 linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic
  linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic
  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  cups cups-bsd cups-client cups-common cups-core-drivers cups-daemon
  cups-ipp-utils cups-ppdc cups-server-common libcups2 libcupscgi1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 linux-generic
  linux-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-headers-generic
  linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-image-generic
  linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 linux-libc-dev linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04
22 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 134 MB of archives.
After this operation, 660 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-ipp-utils amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [210 kB]
Get:2 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcupscgi1 amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [27,4 kB]
Get:3 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-core-drivers amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [27,8 kB]
Get:4 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcupsmime1 amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [13,2 kB]
Get:5 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-server-common all 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [415 kB]
Get:6 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcupsimage2 amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [18,6 kB]
Get:7 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcupsppdc1 amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [45,0 kB]
Get:8 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-common all 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [206 kB]
Get:9 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-ppdc amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [26,8 kB]
Get:10 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-bsd amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [38,4 kB]
Get:11 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-client amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [139 kB]
Get:12 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups-daemon amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [296 kB]
Get:13 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libcups2 amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [211 kB]
Get:14 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 cups amd64 2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5 [191 kB]
Get:15 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic amd64 4.15.0-50.54 [13,0 MB]
Get:16 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic amd64 4.15.0-50.54 [7.917 kB]
Get:17 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic amd64 4.15.0-50.54 [32,7 MB]
Get:18 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-generic amd64 4.15.0.50.52 [1.864 B]
Get:19 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic amd64 4.15.0.50.52 [2.512 B]
Get:20 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-50 all 4.15.0-50.54 [11,0 MB]
Get:21 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic amd64 4.15.0-50.54 [1.113 kB]
Get:22 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic amd64 4.15.0.50.52 [2.472 B]
Get:23 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic amd64 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1 [13,3 MB]
Get:24 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic amd64 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1 [8.160 kB]
Get:25 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic amd64 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1 [32,2 MB]
Get:26 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 4.18.0.20.70 [1.876 B]
Get:27 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 4.18.0.20.70 [2.532 B]
Get:28 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-20 all 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1 [10,5 MB]
Get:29 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic amd64 4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1 [1.105 kB]
Get:30 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 4.18.0.20.70 [2.488 B]
Get:31 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 4.15.0-50.54 [1.007 kB]
Get:32 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04 amd64 4.18.0.20.70 [1.904 B]
Fetched 134 MB in 39s (3.449 kB/s)                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 264444 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-cups-ipp-utils_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-ipp-utils (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../01-libcupscgi1_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcupscgi1:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../02-cups-core-drivers_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-core-drivers (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../03-libcupsmime1_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcupsmime1:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../04-cups-server-common_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking cups-server-common (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../05-libcupsimage2_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../06-libcupsppdc1_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcupsppdc1:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../07-cups-common_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_all.deb ...
Unpacking cups-common (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../08-cups-ppdc_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-ppdc (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../09-cups-bsd_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-bsd (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../10-cups-client_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-client (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../11-cups-daemon_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups-daemon (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../12-libcups2_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcups2:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Preparing to unpack .../13-cups_2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cups (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) over (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../14-linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../15-linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../16-linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Preparing to unpack .../17-linux-generic_4.15.0.50.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.15.0.50.52) over (4.15.0.48.50) ...
Preparing to unpack .../18-linux-image-generic_4.15.0.50.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.15.0.50.52) over (4.15.0.48.50) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.15.0-50.
Preparing to unpack .../19-linux-headers-4.15.0-50_4.15.0-50.54_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-50 (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../20-linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Preparing to unpack .../21-linux-headers-generic_4.15.0.50.52_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic (4.15.0.50.52) over (4.15.0.48.50) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../22-linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic_4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../23-linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic_4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../24-linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic_4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-modules-extra-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../25-linux-generic-hwe-18.04_4.18.0.20.70_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.20.70) over (4.18.0.18.68) ...
Preparing to unpack .../26-linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04_4.18.0.20.70_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.20.70) over (4.18.0.18.68) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.18.0-20.
Preparing to unpack .../27-linux-headers-4.18.0-20_4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.18.0-20 (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../28-linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic_4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../29-linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04_4.18.0.20.70_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-headers-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.20.70) over (4.18.0.18.68) ...
Preparing to unpack .../30-linux-libc-dev_4.15.0-50.54_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-50.54) over (4.15.0-48.51) ...
Preparing to unpack .../31-linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04_4.18.0.20.70_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-signed-generic-hwe-18.04 (4.18.0.20.70) over (4.18.0.18.68) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Setting up cups-server-common (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up cups-common (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.18.0-20 (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Setting up linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.15.0-50-generic (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.15.0-50 (4.15.0-50.54) ...
Setting up linux-modules-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libcups2:amd64 (2.2.7-1ubuntu2.5) ...
Setting up linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic (4.18.0-20.21~18.04.1) ...


Progress: [ 70%] [##########################################..................] ```
````

Comment: or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068828/ubuntu-18-04-stuck-at-upgrading-linux-header

Comment: Future readers: `tlp` is available in the normal Ubuntu repositories. You can add a non-Ubuntu source or PPA if you wish, but are not required to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop it then do this `sudo dpkg --configure -a` see if that will fix the problem.
you may have to reboot also.

Answer (score 0):

You can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (which kills the current process), and press <kbd>↑</kbd> to see the command in the terminal again, then <kbd>enter</kbd> to repeat the command and it should work.

If not then I'd purge my local package cache and repeat the upgrade:

`sudo apt clean && sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

(though personally I use `aptitude` instead of `apt`).

Possibly the server has a bad copy of that headers file, so you could download the same file from [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/linux-headers-4.18.0-20-generic) and then install it with

`sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package`

(replacing the path with the proper one). Once you've done that you can repeat your apt upgrade.